# Best practice to share modules and classes stored in higher directories in Python

Tags: python, module, package

I am writing some scripts for a bigger machine learning application. To keep it nicely structured, I have some subdirectories for different steps, e.g.

```
/
/preprocessing (containing preprocess.py)
/training (containing train.py)
/utils (config.py)
```

So what I would like to have, is a clean possibility to use code from utils in preprocessing and training modules. However, the problem is that I run the code directly in the subdirectories, e.g.

```
cd preprocessing
python3 preprocess.py
```

So this means that preprocessing is my main module and this cannot see anything that is contained in a higher directory, thus I also cannot import modules form utils.

I know that there would be some possibilities that include changing the PYTHONPATH, but I find this somehow ugly. Everybody using my code would have to do this. So my question is if there is a clean and recommended way of importing code from parent or sibling directories.

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative imports as it presented in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references). So you can try something like this in your `preprocess` module:

```
from ..utils import config
```

Comment: Then I get: 'ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package'

Comment: The top answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time answers the question quite good. Short: When calling python modules as scripts, relative imports does not work because __name__ = "__main_". It only works when using python -m my.package.module. Thus, I will switch to deploying my scripts as a package using setuptools.

Comment: Yes, you found a good explanation! If I were you, I would move the running scripts to the top of the project. And in the modules themselves, I would leave only their logic.

Comment: Yes, but than I would have 1000 scripts in the root of the project. I think it is better to install my project using python setup.py install/develop and then just import everything as `from myproject.mymodule import bla`